# @Inject of multiple DAO

Tags: spring, rest, dao, data-access-object

I would inject two DAO in the same service class and I did it as follows:

```
@Transactional
public class TestData {

    private final UserDao userDao;
    private final ExerciseDao exerciseDao;

    @Inject
    public TestData(final UserDao userDao,final ExerciseDao exerciseDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.exerciseDao = exerciseDao;
    }
}
```

Is it the right way ?

In fact, i tried to create a TestData Class to initialize some records fo HSQL dataBase.

So, i injected the two DAO then i used them to create User and it's Exercice.

and when i tried to call getExercices or getUsers REST services trougth HTTP URL an error with 500 status appeared:

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2> <p>Problem accessing Reason: <pre> Request failed.</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

Comment: Off hand, that looks like it should work just fine.  If you're getting an error message, please include that error and its stack trace so we can help you find your problem.

Comment: @BalusC, why did you delete java tag?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Because this question is not about Java SE. The problem is not demonstrable using plain Java application class with `main()` method nor answerable with help of JLS. This question is just about Spring.

Answer (score 1):

*Do you want to hear whether there is possible to inject 2 fields by 1 annotation?*

Yes, it is possible. You have already done this.

*Is that a good practice?*

Personally, I prefer field/setter injections. In this case, I am not dependent on constructors and can prevent unnecessary code. Constructor injection makes your code *container-agnostic*. Whether you use CDI container (e.g. Spring) or not, you have to initialize an instance using this particular constructor.

Comment: Because, it didn't work with me, i got as error 500 error.
How you did it with field injection?

Comment: @Selma, describe your error in details, show the stacktrace